# IOException on bundle generation when opting to generate whole directory structure

Tags: symfony, xampp, bundle, generator

I'm trialling Symfony2 on a Win7 xampp installation and am having a problem with generate:bundle.

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=amd/HelloBundle --format=yml
```

If I select 'yes' (the default being 'no' ) at the question:

*Do you want to generate the whole directory structure*

I get the following message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
Failed to touch H:/<pathToSymfony2Installation>/src//amd/HelloBundle/Resources/doc/index.rst
```

...and of course the rest of the steps don't follow. The correct namespace and bundle directories are created, but things like auto' routing setup for example are never reached.

When selecting the directory to place the source, I choose the default:

```
Target directory [H:/<pathToSymfony2Installation>/src]:
```

(note: no trailing slash)

I notice in the IO exception message there's an additional slash (after 'src') no matter what I do, is this causing the IO error?

If I enter a trailing slash, a further one is added (as you might expect), if I enter the very same as the default - specifically omitting a trailing slash, I still get two slashes after 'src' and before my namespace and bundle names.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar problem like you.  I finally found out the cause: FAT32

I get no problem when I put XAMPP on the NTFS formatted drive. (Drive C or even any portable drive)  However, the error appears when I put XAMPP on the FAT32 formatted drive.  (umm... I guess some PHP functions, like touch(), does not work on FAT32 system correctly)

In addition, I also get other problem (Entity not found) on FAT32 drive when I run this command:

> Symfony> php app/console doctrine:generate:entities xxxxxx

(NOTE: It can be fixed if I disable the auto_mapping and setup the "entity_managers:" in config.yml explicitly)
However, auto_mapping work perfectly once I put the XAMPP back to NTFS drive.

So, you may check your filesystem.  If your XAMPP is placed on FAT32 drive, move it to NTFS drive and and give another try.

Good luck.